# Mongodb find documents based on geoquery and price range?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to query documents with geoNear and also add price range.

```
housePostModel.find(
{
  geoLocation: {
    $geoNear: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [Number(lat), Number(long)],
    },
    $maxDistance: 10000,
  },
  price: { $gte: 0, $lte: Number(rent) },
},
(err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    res.send(result);
  }
}
```

);

I used this but it is not working

My documents look like this

```
    {"_id":{"$oid":"635d016aa6475e2da6e3fc99"},
"adBy":"Uzzam Altaf 2",
"createdBy":"Yt11xVofTuRgSCxgyLBf1rVd41w1",
"postedAt":"24 October 2022",
"title":"House for rent 2",
"phoneNo":"03009554010",
"parking":"Yes",
"electricity":"Yes",
"location":"Sohawa Distt Jhelumn",
"price":18500,
"rooms":"3",
"washrooms":"3",
"images":["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rentpk-94054.appspot.com/o/houseposts%2F7c923038-9d7a-477e-88c5-a63e1cac89c2?alt=media&token=f1df7ee2-d99b-4c55-9a01-8325e6bb5bcb","https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rentpk-94054.appspot.com/o/houseposts%2F7c923038-9d7a-477e-88c5-a63e1cac89c2?alt=media&token=f1df7ee2-d99b-4c55-9a01-8325e6bb5bcb","https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rentpk-94054.appspot.com/o/houseposts%2F7c923038-9d7a-477e-88c5-a63e1cac89c2?alt=media&token=f1df7ee2-d99b-4c55-9a01-8325e6bb5bcb"],
"geoLocation":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[{"$numberDouble":"35.5356665"},{"$numberDouble":"75.126614"}]},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

Can someone help with this. I could not find an answer for last 6 hours.

Comment: The syntax and structure you have are correct (and are working for me), can you elaborate which exactly is "not working".

Comment: Its is returning only the document in which latitude and longitude match except from that the near to that documents are not returned

Comment: I guess they are just not in the provided range, increase your `$maxDistance` and you'll see they get returned

Comment: Max distance is 10000. Is max distance in meters??

Comment: yes it's in meters.

Comment: Thanks. Increasing distance to 40000 works. But i don't get it why it was not working at 10000 as document locations where like 100 meter apart.

Comment: I would verify that the coordinates are as accurate as you think, perhaps there's a different issue

Comment: Well i have 3 document with the same coordinates as provided above but at 10000 it only returns one but at 40000 meter it returns all of them.